# Django database router

Tags: python, django, saas

I'd like to route (change) the database based on the authenticated user. I've looked at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/) but I don't know how to do this upon user login...

I was thinking of adding a field with `database_name` to my custom `UserProfile` and then I'd like to pass this info to the database router which would make the switch...

I don't have any code to show because I simply don't know how to implement this.

This post somehow relates to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740311/django-multi-user-saas).

So the schema would be like:

```
- Users (containing only the `UserProfile`)
 - user1 (containing the app database)
 - user2 (containing the app database)
 - ...
```

Could you point me to the right direction?

Thank you!
BR

Comment: You will probably want to write [a middleware function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) that checks every incoming request, gets the current user and checks a flag in their user profile, routing accordingly.

Comment: What's the relationship between databases and users? Is it a horizontal splitting of user table, or use different DB for model mapping for different users?

Comment: Refer to [this][1] post on how to play around with the routers


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352360/different-database-for-each-django-site/12353583#12353583

Answer (score 1):

Multitenancy in general is a little bit hard to do without twisting django a bit, even though it is a typical request in SaaS applications. Here is a link describing one [approach](http://tidbids.posterous.com/saas-with-django-and-postgresql), the one developed at a company I worked with was a little bit different, hacking the contrib.sites, but the database part is pretty similar.

In short, if you want database multitenancy you are going to have to hack [Django ConnectionHandler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/utils.py#L61) to do what you want.

Comment: This approach is nice... but I don't really need subdomains and I'm kinda new to Django so hacking is a bit of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352360/different-database-for-each-django-site/12353583#12353583) post on how to play around with the routers

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['CustomDatabaseRouter',] #a setting that Django understands.

class CustomDatabaseRouter(object):

  def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
     site_name = get_current_site()
     if site_name  in ['site1']:
         return 'db1'
     if site_name in ['site2']:
        return 'db2'
     return 'default'

  def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
     site_name = get_current_site()
     if site_name  in ['site1']:
         return 'db1'
     if site_name in ['site2']:
        return 'db2'
     return 'default'

  def allow_syncdb(self, model, **hints):
     site_name = get_current_site()
     if site_name in ['site1'] and db == 'db1':
         return True
     if site_name in ['site2'] and db == 'db2':
        return True
     return False
```